# why my react-icon cannot be centered in the button?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-icons

Hi guys so I'm trying to create scroll to Top button in react.js and I have manage to finished the component but the problem is I can't make the icon vertically center on the circle button. How can I fix it ? I've tried to align the item to center. Is it because the Icon itself have some kind of padding on top ?

Here's my code:

```
  return (
        <button onClick={ScrollToTop} className="ButtonToTop" aria-hidden="true" style={{display: isVisible ? 'inline' : 'none'}}>
            <BiArrowToTop/>
        </button>
    )
```

My css code:

```
.ButtonToTop{
    align-items: center;
    position: fixed; 
    width: 50px;
    right: 10px;
    bottom: 40px;
    height: 50px;
    font-size: 33px;
    z-index: 1;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #967A50;
    color: #10255A;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Update

You are setting `style={{ display: isVisible ? "inline" : "none" }}`
which resets the `display` to `inline`. Just set it to `flex` and add the css below (updated)

`style={{ display: isVisible ? "flex" : "none" }}`

---

Use [`Flex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Aligning_Items_in_a_Flex_Container) to easily align it to center

```
.ButtonToTop{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    position: fixed; 
    width: 50px;
    right: 10px;
    bottom: 40px;
    height: 50px;
    font-size: 33px;
    z-index: 1;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #967A50;
    color: #10255A;
}
```

Comment: Hi thankyou for the reply, but it didn't work for me. Any other way ?

Comment: Can you put this code in codesandbox? It will be easier to debug.

Comment: Here you go
https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-leftpad-uwjdw?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @KimSan Check the updated answer

Comment: sorry but nothing change

Comment: Are you sure? because it is working for me, sandbox link below

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-wave-zwm5n?file=/src/ScrollUp.css

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238011/discussion-between-kim-san-and-imanpal-singh).